# Getting an error when I try to run a simple Java - Selenium project

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I try to run this simple project. I have all Selenium JAR files applied in the build path and the `chromedriver` file is located on my desktop:

```
package XYZ;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SeleniumScript {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("websdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://google.com/");
        System.out.print(driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
Juli 20, 2023 11:35:03 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFORMATION: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default; https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#setting-log-output
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/ByteStreams
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.getLogOutput(DriverService.java:471)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.createDriverService(ChromeDriverService.java:417)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.createDriverService(ChromeDriverService.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:507)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:50)
    at rocketlaunch.SeleniumScript.main(SeleniumScript.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 7 more
```

I expect the console to output the page title.

Answer (score 1):

The class `com.google.common.io.ByteStreams` is part of the [Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) libraries. You have to add this library to your class path.
If you use [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), you can add the dependency:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>32.1.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

to your [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model).

If you not use Maven, download the JAR file and add it to the class path manually.

BTW: Take care of Java naming conventions. Package names should be lowercase.